# What is the fastest way to iterate through a dictionary's value in python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

So, I would like to know what is the fastest way to iterate through a dictionary's value and compare it's value to another variable. I have a specific dictionary stucture which is really simple:

```
"data": [
    {
     "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
     "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
     "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
     "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
     "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
     "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
]
```

I already loop through `some_dict['data']` and then compare it's `['id']` value using this code:

```
for item in some_dict:
    if item['id'] == some_value:
        #do stuff
```

But with a large size dictionary, it takes a lot of time so I was curious about other ways to do what i wanted. I heard of set which are good for huge list iteration but is there anyway to use it from my dict structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I see it, your way is OK. But if you insist on a different way then you can do:

```
from itertools import chain
flat_list = list(chain.from_iterable([d.values() for d in some_dict['data']]))
for item in flat_list:
    if item == some_value:
        # do stuff
```

Or, if you only want to check for presence:

```
if some_value in flat_list:
    # do stuff
```

About `set`, if there are duplicates in the `id`'s values, it will eliminate them. So unless thats fine by you, I wouldn't use it.

Comment: It's actually unique ids so `set` wouldn't bother me at all. And would using `chain` or `set` make the process any faster or would the "from dict to chain/set" part make it useless?

Comment: That depends on the size of your dictionary list. If it's "normal" (up to 100 entries or so) then the effect is insignificant. If it's a huge list (more than 10000 entries) then I think you will start noticing some delays. But even then it shouldn't be too bad. You can think about it this way: iterate and then dereference or flatten and then iterate? Please notice that the _amortized worst case_ for `dictionary` get item is `O(n)` while the same action for list is `O(1)`.